# strange behavior for atmel 16

Tags: microcontroller

here is the code

```
#define F_CPU 1000000UL
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <util/delay.h>
#include <avr/interrupt.h>
int main(void)
{

DDRA |= (1 << PA0);
DDRB |= (1 << PB0);
DDRD |= (1 << PD2);

MCUCR |= (1 << ISC01);
GICR |= (1 << INT0);
sei();

while(1)
{


if (PINB == 0b00000001) //when i trigger pbo it will light pa0
{PORTA = 0b00000001;}  

}
              //idont want any thing to happen i want pa0 is on for ever 

}

ISR(INT0_vect)
{
    _delay_ms(10000);

    PORTA ^=(1<<PA0); //toggle pa0

}
```

and the circuit

[image]

the purpose is when i push switch PB0 led connected to PA0 goes on

then when i trigger the interrupt in PD2 this should toggle PA0 to turn it off

the strange thing when i toggle PA0 to turn it off it the led turn on by itself automatically again without triggering the interrupt why??

although this behavior dont happen in Proteus simulation ???

Comment: "and the circuit" - that is not the complete circuit. Where is the power supply? Where are the decoupling capacitors? You have configured PB0 and PD2 as outputs, but you are using them as inputs.

Comment: you are right in every point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Real world switches do not contact cleanly - they bounce and open and close their contacts many times over a few milliseconds before settling to their close position.

Almost certainly what is happening is that when you press the right hand button it closes, then opens again before closing finally.

The initial closure will cause an interrupt but the second closing will cause a pending interrupt to be latched into the processor.

When the ISR exits after toggling the LED there will be the second interrupt pending that will cause the ISR to be entered again.

[image: Switch Bounce example] (From [The Lab Book Pages](http://www.labbookpages.co.uk/electronics/debounce.html))

This is a very common problem and one of the reasons that it is not good practice to connect a switch directly to an interrupt.

The problem can be solved in hardware or software. This site shows some ways [Switch debouncing](http://www.labbookpages.co.uk/electronics/debounce.html).

Also as a matter of software design it is considered bad to put a delay loop within an ISR.  Interrupt service routines should do as little as reasonable and exit quickly.  All the time the ISR is executing the processor cannot process other interrupts. In your example it doesn't matter but in a real system it would.

Comment: thank you sir for your perfect answer and for the advice also :)  but in real circuit i dont use switch actually i use two wires and trigger the interrupt using my hand so do i have the same debouncing problem  ?

Comment: That will probably be even worse...